# Security framework of XStream not initialized, XStream is probably vulnerable

Tags: java, xstream

`Security framework of XStream not initialized, XStream is probably vulnerable`

I keep getting this console error in red while using XStream (1.4.10)

I tried the following:

`XStream.setupDefaultSecurity(xs);`

and

`xs.addPermission(AnyTypePermission.ANY);`
`xs.addPermission(NoTypePermission.NONE);`

none of which got rid of it.

I do not need any fancy security settings, I just want to silence that warning. Maybe also prepare the code for 1.5.x

Answer (score 43, accepted):

When dealing with security issues, I wouldn't take it lightly. Firstly one would understand the severity of the issue, here a [good write up](https://web.archive.org/web/20190404151419/http://blog.diniscruz.com/2013/12/xstream-remote-code-execution-exploit.html) or [another one](https://www.baeldung.com/java-xstream-remote-code-execution).

Then find out how people recommend the solution. The good place to start is from xstream website itself. There is an example which you can use as a starting point on [xstream security page](http://x-stream.github.io/security.html#example).

This would be my set up which basically allows most of your code.

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
// clear out existing permissions and set own ones
xstream.addPermission(NoTypePermission.NONE);
// allow some basics
xstream.addPermission(NullPermission.NULL);
xstream.addPermission(PrimitiveTypePermission.PRIMITIVES);
xstream.allowTypeHierarchy(Collection.class);
// allow any type from the same package
xstream.allowTypesByWildcard(new String[] {
    "com.your.package.**"
});
```

However, after diving more into their source code, this is my take:

```
XStream.setupDefaultSecurity(this); // to be removed after 1.5
xstream.allowTypesByWildcard(new String[] {
    "com.your.package.**"
});
```

So essentially, you will need just one line once upgrading to 1.5.

Please note that you may need more wild cards to suit your application deserialization scenarios. This is not a one-size-fit-all answer but rather a good starting point IMHO.

Comment: First link is broken

Answer (score 12):

I had the same "problem" and solved it by allowing the relevant types:

```
Class<?>[] classes = new Class[] { ABC.class, XYZ.class };
XStream xStream = new XStream();
XStream.setupDefaultSecurity(xStream);
xStream.allowTypes(classes);
```

Maybe this also helps in your case.

Good luck!

Comment: Can I also specify a huge superclass?

Comment: @GGrec NO...i tried passing the superclass but it gave me error for child class.

Answer (score 1):

It also works by specifying an all-inclusive pattern for allowed classes:

```
xstream.allowTypesByRegExp(new String[] { ".*" });
```

Comment: This is basically disabling the security feature that XStream is trying to make you configure. Don't do that unless you don't careabout your application being secure.

Comment: exactly! this needs to be used with caution!

Comment: also, this needs xstream.addPermission(NoTypePermission.NONE); to be called before to disable the warning.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who comes across this, it's likely due to  [CVE-2021-21351](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2021-21351)

XStream has a RCE vulnerability in earlier versions. You should upgrade to 1.46.1 or higher immediately.