# Axon 4 XStream configuration

Tags: spring-boot, axon

When running my Spring Boot app which includes Axon 4 I see the following in my output console:

```
Security framework of XStream not initialized, XStream is probably vulnerable.
```

How do I go about securing the XStream included in Axon 4?

<strike>For clarification, I am speaking about how to configure the XStream that Axon 4 uses. I am not certain if this should be done in the YAML file or in one of the Configuration classes. Every where I have tried the information detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44698296/security-framework-of-xstream-not-initialized-xstream-is-probably-vulnerable) does not affect the XStream configuration and I still get the same warning.</strike>

**Update:**
Based on the answers below, this question seems to be two fold. Thanks to the answers below I managed to get this working as follows (based on information posted at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44698296/security-framework-of-xstream-not-initialized-xstream-is-probably-vulnerable)):

```
    //AxonConfig.java
    @Bean
    XStream xstream(){
        XStream xstream = new XStream();
        // clear out existing permissions and set own ones
        xstream.addPermission(NoTypePermission.NONE);
        // allow any type from the same package
        xstream.allowTypesByWildcard(new String[] {
                "com.ourpackages.**",
                "org.axonframework.**",
                "java.**",
                "com.thoughtworks.xstream.**"
        });

        return xstream;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public Serializer serializer(XStream xStream) {
        return XStreamSerializer.builder().xStream(xStream).build();
    }
```

I didn't want to answer my own question as I think Jan got the correct answer combined with Steven pointing to the Spring Boot config.

I am certain I will need to whittle away at the package scopes and will do so in due course. Thanks Jan and Steven for your assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not Axon specific, check this question for background and solution: [Security framework of XStream not initialized, XStream is probably vulnerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44698296/security-framework-of-xstream-not-initialized-xstream-is-probably-vulnerable)

Comment: Thanks for this but I am still not certain how / where to make those configuration calls for axon to pick it up. I read this answer previously but couldn't figure out where to put it in the initialization sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Jan Galinski is right in that this isn't an Axon specific issue per say. More so a shift within the `XStream` package. Regardless, the link Jan shares is very valuable.

From there, you can create your own `XStream` object, instead of using the one the `XStreamSerializer` creates for you when utilizing Axon. You can then feed that object to the `builder()` of the `XStreamSerializer`.

As you are using Spring Boot too, simply having a bean creation function like so would suffice:

```
// The XStream should be configured in such a way that a security solution is provided
@Bean
public Serializer serializer(XStream xStream) {
    return XStreamSerializer.builder().xStream(xStream).build();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for this. Perhaps the way I phrased the question led to the confusion. In hind sight I think it was probably two questions rolled into one. Jan kindly answered the first question and you answered the second question. I understand the XStream serializer is not an Axon library but as it is included in the Axon libraries perhaps it would be a good idea to list the packages that XStream will need access to? The only way I figured this out was run -> fail -> change -> etc. I appreciate that everyone is super busy and thank you for taking the time to point me in the right direction

Comment: Fair suggestion their Kenneth - I agree there are still improvements to be made in regards to the set up of the `XStreamSerializer`. I can assure you this is still on AxonIQ's radar.